# Trying to understand closed widgets or Where "closed" widgets goes?

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm trying to archive a closable Composite custom widget. I'm studying the Window, Page and TabView classes.

The `close()` method from Window basically just hide the widget, The TabView listen for `close` Page event, then call to `remove(page)` method, this remove the `page` from the internal `pane`, but i don't found a kind of `page.close()`. So, what happened with closed widows and Pages? Still exist?
My own `close()` method must just call to `hide()` method and fire a `close` event just like Window does? This do not carry some memory leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets stay usable until you call `widget.destroy()`, but until then you are free to either hide them or remove them from their parent container.  Once they have been removed from one container, you can reuse them and add them to another container altogether - in the days of IE6 this was a common requirement because it was faster to move unused widgets into a pool and reuse them than to create a new one from scratch (the widget will retain it's DOM elements until it is destroyed).

The `close()` method in `Window` is really just part of the semantics of using a Window - all it really does is remove or hide the Window widget and fire an event, so `close()` and `open()` are (almost) nothing more than nice API sugar to make life easy for the user.

OTOH `Page` doesn't need a `close()` method because adding and removing pages from the `TabView` is the entire concept.

Comment: Thank you, a lot, that clarifies many things no me. :)

But now I have another question: Now days is best destroy the widgets or put it in some place waiting for reusing just like IE6 days? And, that mean I have to take care of do manually clean of each widget that will be shown again, right?

Comment: It's no longer necessary to pool widgets - it's much easier to just `dispose()`  them and forget about it.